# How do i convert a textfile to lower case and find the frequencies of the letters?

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I am writing a code that reads a text file and outputs the frequency of the letters. I used a `FileInputStream` method to read the file and I have no idea on how to convert the uppercase to lower case.

The code runs but only lower case letters are being read. How do i rectify the issue?

Comment: `String.toUpperCase()`, but you should be using `FileReader`, not ``FileInputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution won't convert uppercase to lowercase, but can help you to fix your problem.

As char values come from the ASCII table you could do a second loop like that:

```
char ch = 'A';

for(int i=0; i<26; i++){
    if(d==ch) {
        f[i] += 1;
    }
    ch++;
}
```

or you can modify your condition in your for loop with:

```
if(d==ch || d==(ch-32))
```

You can check the ascii table here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use Java 8 streams and such "new" IO objects as Files and Path, you can do this task pretty simply:

```
Map<Character, Long> freq = Files.lines(Path.of(filepath))        // get stream of file lines
                .flatMap(s -> s.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c))  // convert each line into stream of characters
                .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),    // group by each character
                    Collectors.counting()));                      // count characters in the stream
```

If you need to count only letters, you can additionally filter them:

```
Map<Character, Long> letterFreq = Files.lines(Path.of(filepath))
                .flatMap(s -> s.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c))
                .filter(Character::isLetter)
                .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fairly well.  To convert to lower case see the following:

```
while ((d = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
    d = Character.toLowerCase(d); // <-- add this line here
    char ch = 'a';
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {

       if (d == ch) {               
           f[i] = f[i] + 1;
       }
       ch++;
    }
}
```

A couple other suggestions.

- put a catch block at then end of your `try` block.

```
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

- And when you print out the characters, ignore those with zero count to make your frequency count more readable.
- And primitive number arrays are initialized to 0's so you don't need to do that.